# ZeroBrane: Change color of auto-completion menu...?

Tags: zerobrane

Is there any way to change the color of the auto-completion menu in ZeroBrane (v1.90)?

I have tried all the Tomorrow themes but it seems that the auto-completion menu in all of them is dark text on dark blur background. That does not fit my eyes at all, I cannot read what is highlighted.

[image: ZeroBrane default auto-completion menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible, as this is the only window controlled by Scintilla (an editor component used in the IDE) that doesn't provide a method to change its colors. See [this discussion for details](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20320/change-autocomplete-background-color) (this is related to Notepad++, but it's using the same editor component).

It may be possible to change by switching the color scheme in the OS or the window manager.